# Force the `Click` event to fire - using reflection?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a bunch of buttons on my form, and at a certain point in my code I want to force the `Click` event to fire.  I could do something like this:

```
if (myButton == btnFoo)
  btnFoo_Click(this, new EventArgs());
else if (myButton == btnBar)
  btnBar_Click(this, new EventArgs());
else if // blah blah
  ...
```

Obviously that's not ideal.  This looks like a case for reflection, but I can't find the right method to do it, e.g.

```
var ei = myButton.GetType().GetEvent("Click"); // so far so good;
var mi = ei.GetRaiseMethod(); // always returns null - no good!
```

Documentation for [GetRaiseMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4d2c8dc(VS.96).aspx).

So how can I force the click code to run?

Comment: From that very same page: "This method returns null for events declared with the C# event keyword or the Visual Basic Event keyword. This is because the C# and Visual Basic compilers do not generate such a method."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the PerformClick method:

```
 myButton.PerformClick();
```

Maybe you have to cast to Button, I can't tell from your snippet.  I'll assume you won't need to pursue the reflection code anymore :)

Comment: I hadn't spotted it either. I think I'd still question the overall design in general though - it's at least worth giving it another pass to see if there's a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can't. The point of an event is to allow clients to subscribe and unsubscribe - it should be up to the *publisher* to raise the event. The fact that there even *is* a `GetRaiseMethod` is somewhat odd in my view - and unsupported in C# (you can only specify add/remove methods).

One alternative is to have a `Dictionary<Button, EventHandler>` or something similar, and register all the event handlers there too... but you might want to reflect upon *why* you want to force the click event to effectively fire in the first place. Perhaps there's a better design which would avoid this being an issue.

Comment: Consequently the GetRaiseMethod() doesn't work for C#-generated events, it only works with dynamic code that also uses SetRaiseMethod().  If you use GetRaiseMethod() on C#-generated stuff you'll always get `null'.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue. I have a control which raises a click event when clicked. I want to raise the event when a short-cut key is pressed, this being monitored by a component on my form. To achieve this, I added the following code to my custom control.

```
public void PerformClick()
{            
    OnClick(new EventArgs());
}
```

I then just click the button using

```
ctl.PerformClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet is right; as far as the "contract" is concerned, there's an `add` and `remove` method, and that's about it. In effect, there is no guarantee that the event is implemented as a "field-like" event with a backing multicast delegate. There could be just about any backing data-structure to store each call-back (or none at all). Consequently, "raising an event" on an object is *in general* not well-defined.

Edit: Removed suggestion based on reflection. Go with @Hans Passant.